# Dart не видит класс, импортированный из локальной зависимости

Tags: dart

*Вопрос новичка в Dart: может понадобиться объяснение на пальцах*

Проект состоит из пакетов:

- BusinessRules - бизнес-правила
- Client - клиентская часть приложения
- Server - серверная часть приложения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`Server` использует `BusinessRules`:

```
name: server
version: 0.0.0
publish_to: none

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:

  business_rules:
    path: ../BusinessRules

  args: ^2.0.0
  shelf: ^1.1.0
```

На данный момент `BusinessRules` состоит из двух классов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```yaml
name: business_rules
version: 0.0.0
publish_to: none

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

Пакет `Server` не видит импорт класса `Task`:

```
import "package:business_rules/Enterprise/Task.dart";
```

Ошибка:

```
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:business_rules/Enterprise/Task.dart'.
```

Как правильно импортировать этот класс?

### Важные моменты

- Подразумевается, что ни один из пакетов не будет публиковаться как библиотека. Это значит, что многие поля в `pubspec.yaml` (такие как description и homepage) можно пропустить.
- При внесении изменения в `BusinessRules`, `Client` и `Server` должны тут же быть пересобраны.
- Мне известно, что валидное имя пакета в Dart больших символов содержать не должно, поэтому в `pubspec.yaml` `BusinessRules` называются `business_rules`. Тем не менее, я оставляю за собой право называть директории как считаю нужным.

Comment: Может стоит прочесть [Creating packages](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Название папок/файлов должно быть по стайл гайдам. Иначе можно получить сайд эффекты от анализатора кода.
2. Ваш код в `BusinessRules` расположен не правильно. Он должен лежать в папке `lib` и никак иначе. Это правило касается для любого `dart` проекта.

Расположите ваши папки с `dart` кодом так:

```
BusinessRules/lib/Enterprise/...
BusinessRules/lib/Application/...
BusinessRules/lib/...
```

3. После этого ваш импорт (`import "package:business_rules/Enterprise/Task.dart";`) будет работать.

---

Если вы хотите ограничить видимость некоторых файлов и сделать экспорт более удобным (например: `import "package:business_rules/business_rules.dart";`), то можно поступить следующий образом:

1. Создать файл `business_rules.dart` в папке `lib`
   (`BusinessRules/lib/business_rules.dart`).
2. Перенести все другие папки/файлы с кодом dart в папку src (`BusinessRules/lib/src/...`).
3. В файл `business_rules.dart` добавить экспорты интересующего вас кода:

```
export 'src/Enterprise/Task.dart';
export 'src/Application/...';
export 'src/...';
```

---

*P.S. три точки (`...`) показываются как пример, вместо них нужно указывать полный путь до файла.*

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Правильно ли я понял из второго пункта, что Dart видит файлы внутри зависимости тогда и тогда, когда они находятся в папке `lib`? И ещё: если на момент отложить гайды в сторону, то ли способ переопределить имя папки по умолчанию (`lib`) так, чтобы она была видима также, как и `lib`?

Comment: Да только внутри lib и bin (для CLI). Насколько мне известно механизма смены поиска файлов нет. Но возможно это можно сделать через `analysis_options.yaml` но не уверен в этом...

Comment: Хорошо! Зачёл Ваш ответ и назначил Вам очки репутации.